# Is there a way to tell browsers to ignore cache from before a certain date?

Tags: html, caching

I have an updated stylesheet that I cannot rename or insert any `?nocahce=blah` sort of thing - but browsers are still using a cached version.

Can I put a meta tag in (or something like that) that effectively cancels any cache from a certain date?

Comment: Can you control the headers that get sent by the style sheet?

Comment: @josh then I don't think there is a reliable way without renaming the style sheet, or adding a GET parameter to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the file on the web server, the last modification time of it should change. You can verify this by sending a GET or HEAD request (use a command line tool like `wget`, `curl` or something like `FireBug` to verify).

When the date changes, the browsers should update their caches (unless your browser has a bug).

Comment: First make sure that the date changes. If it doesn't then the browser doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some situations where a client had a very stubborn proxy server on their network that refused to give you a newer version of the file.  We ended up having to rename the css and js files for every release :(